# Why are my package (our'd) variables getting cleared out between PerlChildInitHandler and PerlResponseHandler in mod_perl2?

Tags: apache, mod-perl

I have mod_perl2 running on a virtual host and I'm trying to make my mysql connection persistent between requests to handle server load. I have read all of the documentation and a book on the topic and I still have no idea why this bare-bones implementation of a mod_perl2 web application replies with "It's broken!".

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Apache2::Const;
use Carp qw{croak};
use DBI;

our $mysql_handle;

sub handler {
    print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
    print (defined $mysql_handle ? "It's defined!" : "It's broken!");
    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

sub child_init {
    my ($db, $host, $port, $user, $pass)
      = qw{app_db localhost 3306 app_user app_pass};
    $mysql_handle
      = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=$db;host=$host;port=$port", $user, $pass)
      or croak("Failed to establish a connection with mysqld: $DBI::errstr");
    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

1;
```

This is very strange and makes no sense at all to me. It's as if $mysql_handle is lexically-scoped -- when it's not! Please, can some one explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Apache::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache%3a%3aDBI) for mysql connection persistance in mod_perl.  It overloads DBI's connect and disconnect which allows you to use `DBI->connect(...)` normally, with the added benefit of the code working in or out of a mod perl environment.

As far as the scoping issue, I'd need a little more feedback on your mp setup.  I would try `use vars '$mysql_handle'` or even `$Test::mysql_handle = DBI->connect(...)` and see if you don't get the results you are looking for.